# TypeORM migrations wrong syntax when using PostgreSQL and isGenerated

Tags: mysql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to modify a TypeOrm migration script, already running perfectly with MySQL, to work with PostgreSQL.
I got stuck on some table creation with a generated column:

```
{
  name: 'id',
  type: 'varchar',
  isPrimary: true,
  isGenerated: true,
  generationStrategy: 'uuid',
}
```

Not sure why, but I get the following syntax (I left out the working parts):

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table_name" ("id" NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), <some other fields> , CONSTRAINT "<pk>" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

The migration throws the following error: `error: syntax error at or near "NOT"`, which I narrowed down to the obvious problem of no type declaration between `"id"` and `NOT`

If I remove the `isGenerated` from the config, the type appears and everything works but without the `DEAFAULT uuid_generate_v4` part.

I'm not sure what could be the problem, and I'd appreciate your help

Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

Your id type must be 'uuid' to match generation strategy, like this:

```
{
  name: 'id',
  type: 'uuid',
  isPrimary: true,
  isGenerated: true,
  generationStrategy: 'uuid',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use MYSQL we need to know that does not exist `NOT NULL`, exist `IS NOT NULL`.
So your code will be
`CREATE TABLE "my_table_name" ("id" IS NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), <some other fields> , CONSTRAINT "<pk>" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`.

[https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/is_not_null.php#:~:text=Example%20%2D%20With%20SELECT%20Statement,not%20contain%20a%20null%20value](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/is_not_null.php#:%7E:text=Example%20%2D%20With%20SELECT%20Statement,not%20contain%20a%20null%20value).

Comment: The migration "SQL" is being generated by Typeorm. The problem is not with Mysql, it's with Postgresql

Comment: Could you post your migration?